# SQL: Duplicating data under a separate header

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I'm fairly new at coding in SQL and am wondering if there's a way I can achieve the attempted result of the following statement:

```
SELECT CASE sc.descrip 
        WHEN 'x' THEN 'option1' AND 'option2'
        ELSE sc.descrip 
    END as description
FROM status_code sc
```

Unfortunately 'AND' doesn't work this way with case statements.

Thanks,

---

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
Example  | Duration
ShovelA  | 3    
ShovelB  | 5  
ShovelC  | 7  
ShovelD  | 9  



Example     | Duration
A/B Shovels | 8  
All Shovels | 24
```

Comment: You must return one value in case. Can you provide us with test data and expected result?

Comment: Do you mean "All Shovels | 24" as 3+5+7+9 = 24, not 28?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing this would be [UNION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx)ing many SELECTs each with their own aggregations, e.g.

```
SELECT "A/B Shovels" AS Example, Sum(Duration) AS Duration
FROM status_code
WHERE Example in ("ShovelA", "ShovelB")
UNION
SELECT "All Shovels" AS Example, Sum(Duration) AS Duration
FROM status_code
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 'A/B Shovels' as Example,sum(Duration) From status_code 
       Where Right(Example,1) in ('A','B')
union 
Select 'All Shovels' as Example,sum(Duration) From status_code
```